# how do i control the length of the (hover)appearing border?

Tags: html, css, sass

Hi Im making a website for my portfolio and need some help with a styling problem I've ran into.
I'll show you how mine looks and then follow up with the template I'm trying to replicate.

[image]

[image]

on the bottom one the border appears as if the different texts have a box they're in. If you understand what I mean.

my code is as follows;

Sass:

```
.header{
nav {
    padding: 2rem 30rem;
    background: $blackish;
}        
&__links {
    a {   
        font-size: $font-med;
        margin-right: 6.25rem; 
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: $boltyellow;
        padding: 1.9rem 0rem;
        border-bottom-color: $boltyellow;
    } 
}
}
```

Html:

```
<header class = "header">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <nav class = "flex">
        <div class="header__links">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Order</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You probably want some padding left and right on your `a` instead of margin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion worked. I don't know how to accept your comment as the right answer, doesn't let me.

Comment: Well, don't worry, I'm not sure that a full answer was worth it, happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with before or after Pseudo-classes

```
a:after{
  content:'';
  width:0;
  height:3px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  display: block;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

a:hover:after{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help. I appreciate the answer. I simply had to change the padding as @Amaury Hanser said. Thanks anyways :)